# Using jquery mobile and json in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-mobile

I have a simple rails app the displays a list of items and i want to create a native mobile app using jquery mobile and the items would be featched from the main site.
my controller is

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
    @lists = List.all
    respond_with(@lists)
  end

  # ...
end
```

then in my native mobile app i have this in my index.html page

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/lists",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

this data is fetched and i would like it to be appended in the jquery mobile template inside the li tab. How can i do this using jquery. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Simple test app</h1>
        </div> 
    <div data-role="content">
         <ul>
          <li>(content appends here)</li>
         </ul>
        </div> 
    <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>test app</h4>
        </div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

the json output example is below

[image: json output]

Comment: What does your JSON output look like? Can you post an example?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your JSON output. `serverResponse[0].list.title` will output the first title and `serverResponse[1].list.title` will output the second. My example shows how to iterate through all of the returned objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX call you can set a `success` callback function in which you can append the server-response to the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
    url         : "http://localhost:3000/lists",
    dataType    : "json",
    type        : "GET",
    processData : false,
    contentType : "application/json",
    success     : function (serverResponse) {

        //setup an output variable to buffer the output
        var output = [];

        //since you aren't telling the `.ajax()` function to parse your response you need to do it here so the string returned from the server is an object
        serverResponse = $.parseJSON(serverResponse);

        //iterate through the results, assuming the JSON returned is an array of objects
        for (var i = 0, len = serverResponse.length; i < len; i++) {
            output[output.length] = '<a href="#' + serverResponse[i].list.id + '">' + serverResponse[i].list.title + '</a><br />';
        }

        //now append all the output at once (this saves us CPU cycles over appending each item separately)
        $('[data-role="content]').children('ul').children('li').eq(0).html(output.join(''));
    }
});
```

You should add an ID or class to some element in your HTML markup so you can find only the LI you want. If you give your `data-role="page"` an ID you can target the `LI` you want with this:

$('#page-id').children('[data-role="page"]').children('ul').children('li').eq(0);

The `.eq(0)` is there just in-case there are multiple `LIs` in the `UL` element.

Here is some light reading for ya about the above code:

- `$.parseJSON()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/
- `.join()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
- `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq
- Fast Loops: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give the ajax a callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/lists",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  processData: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(transport){
   insertMyStuff(transport);
  }
});
```

I like to move callback logic out of the ajax block:

```
insertMyStuff = function(transport){
  $("#my_li_id").append(transport);
  //or iterate over your json however you like here
}
```

You'll need to give the `<li>` an id for jquery to find it with that approach.  Here is a simple way:

```
<li id="my_li_id">(content appends here)</li>
```

Comment: Any reason to make two functions instead of one? Can't you just put the `insertMyStuff` code directly into the `success` callback function? Also if JSON is returned you won't want to just append it to the DOM, you would want to iterate through the JSON object add just the desired information to the DOM.

Comment: One would suffice here.  I am just in the habit of moving callback logic to another function to keep my ajax blocks more concise...

Comment: very nice. would go trough it